Accessing RDS transaction logs
Greetings to everyone from a newcomer to this forum!
There is an RDS MySQL 5.7 database the transaction logs of which I would like to inspect: more specifically, upon attempting to add foreign keys to some of the tables I discovered cases in which the child table stores data on the foreign_key column which doesn't exist in the corresponding primary_key column of the parent table. I thus need to rely on the transaction logs in order to:

understand the reason behind such occurrences as described above (data present only in the child table)
subsequently, identify the appropriate remedy to the problem, with the end goal of eliminating child/parent discrepancies and hence enabling the introduction of the desired foreign keys.

There is a Logs & events tab available in the interface for the DB in question, however it only holds limited data (limited to the current month, by what it seems). Where should I expect to be able to access a more detailed, historical transaction log? (as it may well be that those SQL transactions having led to the forementioned discrepancies took place somewhere in the past 2 years or perhaps even earlier).
Thank you for your time and attention!
